# Gorilla sessions not working for CORS from client

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I have set up a Go rest api. And on login I do this:

```
session, _ := store.New(r, sessionId)
session.Options.MaxAge = 12 * 3600
err := session.Save(r, w)
//treat error
```

and for checking the session i have smth like this:

```
    session, err := store.Get(r, sessionId)
    //treat error
    if session.IsNew {
        http.Error(w, "Unauthorized session.", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }
```

If I do the requests from postman it works fine, but when I do them from my client I get 401. Has any of you experienced something like this? The store is a CookieStore.

I already checked the id's, I replaced sessionId variable with a static string. Gorilla session uses gorilla context to register a new request and when I do the request from postman `context.data[r]` is not null, but from the client it is always null -> always a new session.

https://github.com/gorilla/context/blob/master/context.go - line 33

it is called in

https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/sessions.go - line 122

wich is used in the CookieStore.Get function in

https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/store.go - line 77

EDIT 1:
For the client I use polymer and I tried xmlhttp too.
Polymer:

```
<iron-ajax
  id="ajaxRequest"
  auto
  url="{{requestUrl}}"
  headers="{{requestHeaders}}"
  handle-as="json"
  on-response="onResponse"
  on-error="onError"
  content-type="application/json"
  >
</iron-ajax>
```

and the handlers

```
  onResponse: function(response){
    console.log(response.detail.response);
    this.items = response.detail.response
  },
  onError: function(error){
    console.log(error.detail)
  },
  ready: function(){
    this.requestUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/fingerprint/company/" + getCookie("companyId");
    this.requestHeaders = {"Set-cookie": getCookie("api_token")}
  }
```

and the cookie successfully reaches the backend.

And xmlhttp:

```
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
        //do stuff
      }else if(xmlhttp.status == 401){
        page.redirect("/unauthorized")
      }else{
        page.redirect("/error")
      }
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/api/fingerprint/company/" + getCookie("companyId"),true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Set-cookie", getCookie("api_token"));
  xmlhttp.send();
```

EDIT 2:

So I tried debugging with fiddler(thanks for the suggestion) and i found out that the request from postman has an bold entry `Cookies / Login` and the request from the client does not. Any idea how to get/set that value? It is somehow automatically set in Postman. In the authentication request I get a set-cookie header that has all the data that I need but I can't get it on the client. I get `Refused to get unsafe header set-cookie`.

Comment: Seems like this might be a problem with how your client handles cookies. Could you add the client code?

Comment: Can you use another tool like fiddler to inspect and provide the request headers and body for both cases? My approach to this problem would be, fiddle each, copy the data into a text editor, compare the two, make it so my clients request is identical to Postmans.

Comment: When you say from the "client", is this on the same domain? Sounds like it's not.

Comment: The word CORS is in the title => it`s not the same domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the client the requests need to have `withCredentials = true` and after that the browser deals with everything. It gets the cookie from the `set-cookie` header and it sends the cookies via the `cookie` header. So, after all, it was not a gorilla sessions problem.

Comment: For those seeking clarification on withCredientials, this is part of the XMLHttpRequest object, so in the original post, the user would need to add the `xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;` line.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having the same problem I was having and you want to whitelist all domains/wildcards (or have a list of domains in an array you can scan through), you can do something like this.

```
domain_raw := r.Host
domain_host_parts := strings.Split(domain_raw, ".")
domain := domain_host_parts[1] + "." + domain_host_parts[2]
domains := getDomains() // stores a slice of all your allowable domains
has_domain := false
for _, d := range domains {
    if d == domain {
        has_domain = true
        break
    }
}

if has_domain == false {
    return
} else {
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://"+domain_raw)
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
}
```

I love go